# Outlook 2016 won't connect to Office 365 anymore after LogMeIn Himachi install

Tags: microsoft-outlook, vpn, remote-desktop, office365, logmein

I installed Bitdefender and Hamachi successfully on my desktop; however, after installing Hamachi, my Outlook can't connect to the server anymore.

I uninstalled Hamachi and it works again so I concluded that Bitdefender is not the issue.

Does anyone have experience with these or similar issues?

Comment: I have Office 2016 and Himacho installed and I have no problem connecting to Office 365

Comment: Aren't we talking about Hamachi by LogMeIn? Perhaps Outlook 2016 is using a different route (failing) with Hamachi installed. Did you try this? https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/scottos/2013/07/25/outlook-cant-connect-to-office-365/

Answer (score 1):

So I used the microsoft support and recovery assistant for Outlook 365 and it suggested to disable IpV6 on the (wireless) network adapter...this seemed to have fixed the problem. Is this not going to affect my normal internet usage?

edit: I had to disable ipv6 on both wireless and hamachi adapter, then outlook connected, and then I could enable ipv6 again on the hamachi adapter as it requires ipv6 to work.

Answer (score 0):

I would check a few things.

1. Go thru device manager and update the drivers, just point it at existing Hamachi folder.
2. Make sure the logmein tunnel service is running.

I would also look to see if any routes were added to your system when it was installed. These may or may not be correct.  This article here shows you how to work with windows route tables if you are not familiar:  http://www.windowsnetworking.com/articles-tutorials/trouble/Making-Sense-Windows-Routing-Tables.html